# ¿Como convertir un dato de tipo string, para convertirlo en minutos? Utilizando SQL Server y MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero convertir un dato de tipo varchar a int, después el resultado lo quiero convertir a minutos para de ahí sacar un promedio. Este es el campo:

```
RalentiTiempoTotal
    01:06:10
```

Lo que estoy haciendo primero es separar los campos de esta manera:

```
select sum (convert(float, substring(RalentiTiempoTotal,1,2))/60 + 
       convert(int, substring(RalentiTiempoTotal,4,2))/3600)
       from Tabladatos
```

En el primer select lo que hago, estoy convirtiendo horas a minutos y después los minutos a segundos. Pero no me da el resultado que deseo.

Sé que en MySQL, hay una función(TIME_TO_SEC), que sirve para calcular los minutos directamente. ¿Cuál sería el equivalente a SQL Server?.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar por favor?
Gracias.

Comment: _Quiero convertir un dato de tipo varchar a int, después el resultado lo quiero convertir a minutos para de ahí sacar un promedio_ ¿Por qué quieres convertirlo 1º a `int`, si quieres puedes convertir tu String en minuto directamente. No sé si lo que quieres es calcular el total de minutos de toda la cadena. Hay una confusión porque mezclas minutos-segundos en tu planteamiento. **¿Quieres obtener el total de minutos o el total de segundos de una hora dada, es eso**?

Comment: Es correcto, deseo el total de minutos.

Comment: Hola Ric_hs. Noto que agregastes SQL Server a la pregunta, pero la pregunta la tienes etiquetada con MySQL. Y antes tenías la etiqueta plsql  (que apunta a Oracle) que removí. Sería bueno tener cuidado de no agregar confusión a la pregunta, ni tampoco es ideal de que sigas cambiando la pregunta una vez que ya se ha contestado y aceptado, porque esto puede invalidar buenas respuestas existentes.

Comment: Ok. Muchas gracias. No vuelve a pasar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### `MySQL`

Podrias solucionarlo usando [`TIME_TO_SEC`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) y al resultado lo divides por `60`

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(RalentiTiempoTotal) / 60
```

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://rextester.com/YFZWA17297)

### `SQL Server`

Usando `CAST` para convertir el `time` a `datetime`, luego `DATEDIFF` para obtener el `timestamp` en segundos, multiplicamos por `1.0` para convertir el `int` a `float` y luego dividimos por `60`.

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT total_minutos = DATEDIFF(second,0,CAST(@time as datetime)) * 1.0 / 60
```

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://rextester.com/DXIMA80785)

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!, si me funciono... Nota: No quería darte calificación mala, creo que me confundi.

Comment: @Ric_hc Esta es la mejor respuesta, creo que debes marcarla como solución. Como te decía en el comentario, MySQL tiene una función para convertir una cadena de tiempo en segundos directamente, dividiendo entre 60 obtienes los minutos: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec No hay necesidad de hacer conversiones a `int`

Comment: @MarcosGallardo Sí, se me escapó, pero ya está.

Comment: Una pregunta: Hay alguna función que sea utilizada para SQL server, me refiero a "TIME_TO_SEC" pero, para SQL Server?

Comment: @Ric_hc eso es tema para otra pregunta :P

Comment: Ok, la formulo gracias.

Comment: Marcos Gallardo: Claro que si, muy buena... Me referia a la respuesta de "TIME_TO_SEC".

Comment: Ok. Listo. Gracias.

Comment: Que es <kbd>esto</kbd>?

Comment: @Ric_hc, he actualizado mi respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias Marcos. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo el siguiente escenario

```
SELECT hora, 
       1*LEFT(hora,2) as horas, 
       1*RIGHT(LEFT(hora,5),2) as minutos, 
       1*right(hora,2) as segundos
FROM 
(SELECT '00:06:10' as hora) t1
```

El resultado sería:

```
    hora        horas   minutos segundos
    00:06:10    0       6       10
```

Si quieres llevarlo todo a minutos el total se calcula como

```
   horas * 60 + minutos + segundos/60
```

Lo que en este caso sería

```
SELECT hora, 
       1*LEFT(hora,2)*60 + 
       1*RIGHT(LEFT(hora,5),2) +
       1*right(hora,2)/60 as minutos
FROM 
(SELECT '00:06:10' as hora) t1
```

Y el resultado de eso son 6.16666666 minutos

Fiddle: http://rextester.com/EZZM62277

Comment: ¡¡Excelente!! De los 2 método me funciono correctamente. Muchas gracias a todos por su tiempo.